# Styling toLocaleTimeString() AM/PM output

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following:

```
myClock();
function myClock() { 
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});   
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = d; 
}
setInterval(myClock, 1000);
```

***Output:*** 11:47 AM

How could I style the AM/PM separately? (like giving it a smaller font-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split your string, place PM in a span, style the span.  Let me know if this works for you.

```js
myClock();
function myClock() { 
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});  
    
    var ds = d.split(' ')
    ds[1] = '<span id="pm">'+ds[1]+'</span>'
    
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = ds[0]+ " " + ds[1]; 
}
setInterval(myClock, 1000);
```

```css
#pm{
color:green;
text-transform: lowercase;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='clock'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want lowercase, just call `.toLowercase()` on `d` (first example).

Otherwise you can break each individual section part and style them separately with CSS.

You could separate hours from minutes from the `:` etc. Just follow the same pattern provided.

```js
myClock();
function myClock() { 
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = d.toLowerCase(); 
    document.querySelector("#clock2 > span:first-child").textContent = d.split(' ')[0];
    document.querySelector("#clock2 > span:last-child").textContent = d.split(' ')[1];
}
setInterval(myClock, 1000);
```

```css
#clock2 span:first-child {
  color: green;
}

#clock2 span:last-child {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
<div id="clock2"><span></span> <span></span></div>
```